# errors installing groovy on mac osx homebrew (pydot)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting the following error while trying to do a fresh install of groovy on my mac (10.7.5) with homebrew:

Any suggestions?

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y
executing command [sudo pip install -U pydot]
Password:
Downloading/unpacking pydot
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pydot
    Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible.
    
Downloading/unpacking pyparsing (from pydot)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyparsing
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/Users/mike/ros_catkin_ws/build/pyparsing/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pyparsing import __version__ as pyparsing_version
      File "pyparsing.py", line 629
        nonlocal limit,foundArity
                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/Users/mike/ros_catkin_ws/build/pyparsing/setup.py", line 9, in <module>

    from pyparsing import __version__ as pyparsing_version

  File "pyparsing.py", line 629

    nonlocal limit,foundArity

                 ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/mike/.pip/pip.log
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  pip: command [sudo pip install -U pydot] failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58786/errors-installing-groovy-on-mac-osx-homebrew-(pydot)/) by [Mike Bosse](https://answers.ros.org/users/4488/mike-bosse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-03-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like pyparsing switched its default version to py3k only:

http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/News

I guess you will have to install version 1.5.7 explicitly:

```
$ sudo pip install pyparsing==1.5.7
```

I haven't run into this, but I assume that's because I already have pyparsing installed from before this change.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes pyparsing needs to be version 1.5.7, but I needed to run the following commands to get it to work:

```
easy_install pyparsing==1.5.7
easy_install pydot
```

since the rosdep install for pydot would get its own (incorrect) version of pyparsing.

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [Mike Bosse](https://answers.ros.org/users/4488/mike-bosse/) with karma: 41 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To kind of sort out what @William and @Mike Bosse posted, I had to run:

```
$ sudo easy_install pyparsing==1.5.7
$ sudo easy_install pydot
$ sudo pip install pyparsing==1.5.7
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1